# Why can't you set the modalPresentationStyle during the transition?

Tags: ios

i have 2 view controllers, `VCA` and `VCB`. I transition from `VCA` to `VCB` with `presentViewController(VCB, animated: true, completion: nil)` and got back with `dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` in `VCB`. This transition is managed by a custom `TransitionManager` instance with both `VCA` and `VCB` having their own `TransitionManager` instance as their `transitioningDelegate`'s.

I want `VCB` to be presented over the top of `VCA` so in `VCB`'s initialiser I add:

```
convenience init() {
    self.init()
    modalPresentationStyle = .OverFullScreen
}
```

This works.

However, if I remove `modalPresentationStyle = .OverFullScreen` from `VCB`'s initialiser, and try to set it in the `TransitionManager` class in the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` delegate as follows

```
func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning!
    let toVC = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)!
    toVC.modalPresentationStyle = .OverFullScreen

    // do animation ...
}
```

the effect doesn't work. Why is this the case, please?

**Edit**

It seems that `modalPresentationStyle.rawValue` is 0 (`.FullScreen`) in `VCB`'s `viewDidLoad` and then 5 (the wanted value, `OverFullScreen`) in `VCB`'s `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple documentation states **To change the transition type, you must set this property before presenting the view controller.**

Comment: For future users, this quote is from: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621388-modaltransitionstyle